# Clicking on an element of a webpage in Safari using it's title

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to use Automator to download a bunch of .mp4 files without much interaction from me. I'm able to do the actual downloading already, but the problem is that the links to the files are on different pages. There's a "next" button that I can click on, but to make the process automatic, I'd like to do that with AppleScript. I've read through some other posts, but all of them required that the element had a class or a name. When I inspect the element, I see this:`<a title="Next Episode" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff" href="/?13197&amp;s=15&amp;tv=1">
&gt;
</a>`. I tried doing this: 
`tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('Next Episode').click();" in current tab of first window
end tell`
but that didn't work, as I expected. How do I use the title to find the element?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript at this level is pretty easy to learn, the tutorials at http://w3schools.com are fun. You really have to use getElementsByTag("a") to get your anchor tags, and then iterate over those, to find elements with the title attribute set to "Next". Maybe I could provide a solution that would work for you, but I suggest you try to write it yourself. However, you'll find a piece of AppleScript/Javascript that do almost exactly what you want to do over at http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/30/safari-link-sniffing (look for a link to Safari next page, I really do encourage you to read the page though.)

HTH